# Why won't this checkbox refresh as expected in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'd like to simplify the [TodoMVC app](https://github.com/marcandre/todomvc/tree/meteor_bug) for meteor. There is currently some `observe` that should not be needed I think. I simplified a bit successfully, but when [I try to simplify it](https://github.com/marcandre/todomvc/compare/marcandre%3ameteor_simplify...marcandre%3ameteor_bug) further the updating doesn't work properly.

For instance, it should get selected when I click on all the items in the todo list but doesn't. When I refresh the page it is selected though.

**Edit**: Got rid of an unrelated error, thanks to @TomColeman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it simply was because the correct html is `checked="checked"`, not simply `checked`.

Comment: I guess maybe you should just delete this question now? I don't know if it offers much help to anyone else given the resolution. :)

Comment: I tried already but can't, as it has answers... so I voted to close it... I can't even accept my answer for another day :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing that error before the patch is applied. It's due to the `Meteor.flush` on line 74.

I'm not sure why that flush is needed? (I'm also not sure why there's an error either).

Comment: Good catch! Indeed, does not seem related. So I edited my answer after I take out the `flush`